# RSS/Atom Feed for website

Tags: rss, atom-feed

I am new to RSS/Atom feeds and there are a couple of points that I don't quite understand from doing some basic research.

Firstly, how do I tell if a website has an RSS/Atom feed? I can't see an icon for it on the website but is there anything else I can look at that will give me an indication that there is a feed?

Secondly, if there isn't an RSS/Atom Feed, is it going to be possible to create an RSS/Atom feed that will always be up-to-date without being a webmaster of the site? I am essentially wanting to use an RSS/Atom feed to get web pages that have products that are going to be resold on another website. Is this going to be possible if these pages aren't already in an RSS/ATOM feed? I know there are tools that allow you to make an RSS Feed of any webpage but I believe you have to re-do it if any content changes.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find out if a site offers an RSSAtom feed, use [feed auto-discovery](http://blog.superfeedr.com/rss-autodiscovery/).

No, if you're not the publisher of the site, you can't publish an RSS feed which is consistently up to date.